# Odoo Procurement group dynamic run

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14

I'm trying to make the production check availability dynamically with my custom function.
This is my function where the MO is being creating with the quantity difference for the child.
I want to create the child MO with the ID linked with the source procurement group. The fields that i need to pass is:

- Origin
- Quantity

```
        origin = self.name
        procurement_group_id = self.procurement_group_id
        uom_reference = stock_move.product_id.uom_id
        quantity = stock_move.product_uom._compute_quantity((stock_move.product_uom_qty - stock_move.reserved_availability), uom_reference)
        try:
            procurement_group_id.with_context(clean_context(self.env.context)).run([
                procurement_group_id.Procurement(
                    stock_move.product_id, # Product
                    quantity, # Qty
                    uom_reference, # UoM
                    stock_move.warehouse_id.lot_stock_id,  # Location
                    origin,  # Name
                    origin,  # Origin
                    stock_move.warehouse_id.company_id,
                    {
                        'warehouse_id': stock_move.warehouse_id,
                        'route_ids': stock_move.route_ids,
                        'date_planned': stock_move.date,
                        'group_id': procurement_group_id,
                    } 
                )
            ])
        except UserError as error:
            raise UserError(error)
```

How can i have returned the id of document created?

I tried to search with reference on the database and retrieve the ID but sometimes it gets double+ ids returned. So i don't have trust of the datas returned.